# Xamarin Android wait for button click

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In my xamarin android app, I'm trying to login with facebook account. If a Facebook account does not have the email address, I'm setting new content view with input and save button, how can I wait for a button click to continue the previous content view work?

this is my code where I'm creating a new content view and want to wait for button click:

```
public void OnCompleted(JSONObject @object, GraphResponse response)
{
    var email = @object.Get("email").ToString();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    {               
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CompleteRegistrationView);

        //At this point, I want to wait until the user enters the email address and clicks the button. After that, I want to execute this method
        var button = FindViewById(Resource.Id.save_email_btn);

        button.Click += (s, arg) => {
            email = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.email_value).Text;
            CloseContextMenu();
        };

    }
    ((LoginViewModel)ViewModel).SaveUserCommandHandler();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use modal dialog? In android you could use DialogFragment with desired content and enable buttons when you want. Don't forget SetCancelable=false; for avoid back button press.